# SQL group by several fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, clickhouse

Why does this mistake appear?

"Code: 43, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Illegal type (Enum8('' = 0, 'Manhattan' = 1, 'Bronx' = 2, 'Brooklyn' = 3, 'Queens' = 4, 'Staten Island' = 5)) of 2 argument of function and (version 20.3.4.10 (official build))"

```
select pickup_boroname as region, toHour(pickup_datetime) as time_, count(payment_type_) as pay_count
from datasets.trips_mergetree
where pickup_date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31' and
      pickup_boroname != 0
group by time_ and region
order by pay_count desc;
```

Comment: In the table there are taxi data:

pickup_boroname - city region(enum8) pickup_date - trip data ;pickup_datetime - data and time of trip;

I can't get count of payment by time and region:

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Does it work if you in the where clause write: pickup_boroname != '' instead of pickup_boroname != 0 ? Also what are the column types for these columns?

Comment: @Sourcery, it's enum8 : "" - 0 (empty string), 'Manhattan' - 1 etc

Comment: @jarlh sorry for my english, it's translator

Comment: If someone has the same problem, error was because of ```group by time_ and region```, i have to write ```group by time_ , region```

Answer (score 1):

Group by would not normally take a boolean expression.  I think you want:

```
select pickup_boroname as region, toHour(pickup_datetime) as time_, 
       count(payment_type_) as pay_count
from datasets.trips_mergetree
where pickup_date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31' and
      pickup_boroname <> 0
group by time_, region
order by pay_count desc;
```

I replaced the `!=` with `<>`, but there may be problems with that as well, depending on the type of `pickup_boroname`.  You probably intend:

```
pickup_boroname is not null
```

Comment: Type of pickup_boroname is Enum8('' = 0, 'Manhattan' = 1, 'Bronx' = 2, 'Brooklyn' = 3, 'Queens' = 4, 'Staten Island' = 5)) of 2 argument of function and (version 20.3.4.10 (official build))", i.e. pickup_boroname != 0 is necessary to ignore trips where the region is not empty string(empty string in enum corresponds 0). I tried your decision, but it didn't help

Comment: @iamhdq . . . Did you use `pickup_boroname is not null`?

Comment: yes, and i think that problem isn't here, because if i write just ```where pickup_date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31' ``` without "pickup_boroname != 0" ,error is the same

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Try the latest stable release 20.3.5.21

```
SELECT
    pickup_boroname AS region,
    toHour(pickup_datetime) AS time_,
    count(payment_type_) AS pay_count
FROM trips_mergetree
WHERE ((pickup_date >= '2011-01-01') AND (pickup_date <= '2011-12-31')) AND (pickup_boroname != 0)
GROUP BY
    time_,
    region
ORDER BY pay_count DESC

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm updated datagrip in Ubuntu and seems there is no bug fixed , but in Windows it works. Thanks again!